# Spark Float Conversion (Python)

Tags: python, apache-spark

So I have the following function that takes out non-digits:

```
def filterWithAccum(a):
    if [item for item in a if item.isdigit()]:
        b = 1
    else:
        accum.add(1)
    return [item for item in a if item.isdigit()]
```

Which runs just fine with this RDD:

```
columnRDD = dataSplit.map(lambda line: columnGrab(line, column)).filter(filterWithAccumNum).map(lambda line: float(line))
```

What I was hoping to do was take out the last map and during the .filter function also convert to float like so:

```
def filterWithAccumNum(a):
    if [item for item in a if item.isdigit()]:
        b = float(a)
    else:
        accum.add(1)
    return b
```

But I get the following error:

```
 File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.1-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.12/lib/spark/python/pyspark/statcounter.py", line 45, in merge
    delta = value - self.mu
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'float'
```